# Comando para definir um valor padrão para uma coluna no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá, desejo saber o comando para definir um valor como *default* no SQL server.

O nome da tabela é "Tabela" e o nome da coluna que desejo alterar é "COLUNA2".

Answer (score 3):

Para definir um valor padrão de uma coluna da tabela você deve utilizar o operador `DEFAULT`. Você pode informá-lo na criação da sua tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  coluna1 VARCHAR(100),
  coluna2 INT DEFAULT 1
);
```

Ou para alterar a coluna:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD CONSTRAINT coluna2_default DEFAULT 1 FOR coluna2;
```

Nos exemplos acima o valor 1 será definido na coluna caso não seja informado na inserção:

```
INSERT INTO tabela(id, coluna1)
            VALUES(1, 'blablabla');
```

Resultando no registro:

```
| id  | coluna1   | coluna2 |
| --- | --------- | ------- |
| 1   | blablabla | 1       |
```

> [**Usar o Transact-SQL para especificar um padrão**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-2017#TsqlProcedure)
>
> Há várias maneiras pelas quais você pode especificar um valor padrão para uma coluna usando o SSMS para enviar o T-SQL.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta

Comment: @JulioCesarAndrade não esqueça de aceitar a resposta caso a mesma tenha lhe ajudado

Answer (score 1):

Julio, boa tarde!

Se você já configurou a tabela para ter um valor default na criação da mesma, não há necessidade de passar valor para a coluna quando efetuar o insert.

Exemplo de criação com valor Default:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    City varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Sandnes'
);
```

Comment: No caso eu não configurei, mas achei a resposta. Agradecido!